# Jquery ajax, wait until images or iframe are fully loaded before firing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, vimeo-api

I am working on putting together an online portfolio. When a user clicks on a certain project, I am trying to load the project information using ajax and insert it into the current page. The issue I'm having is that the function that runs on load() success doesn't know when the content is fully loaded so jquery attempts to run the animation that unhides the div before everything is loaded. The page I am loading has one of two types of content (or both). It either has images or and iframe for a Vimeo embed.

Here is my code:

```
//On project click, run function
$j(".project-ajax-click").click(function(e){

    var pageLoad = $j(this).prop("href");

    //Bring project div to the top of page
    $j('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop': $j('#project').offset().top-$j('.navbar').height()}, 900, 'swing');

    $j('.project-container')
        .slideUp()
        .load(pageLoad, function(){
            $j(".project-flex").flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                slideshow: false,
                directionNav: false,
                controlNav: false,
            });

            $j('.flex-prev, .flex-next').on('click', function(){
                var href = $j(this).attr('href');
                $j('.project-flex').flexslider(href)
                return false;
            });

            $j(".project-close").click(function(e){
                $j('.project-container').slideUp(function(){
                    $j('.project-info').remove(); 
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $j('.project-container').slideDown();
        });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is an example of the content ajax would be loading (this project includes one vimeo slide and two images).

```
<div class="project-ajax">
    <div class="project-flex">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li><div class="vimeo-wrapper"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/75576745" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/640x480" width="100%"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/640x480" width="100%"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="project-description">
        <h1>Project Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec imperdiet massa nec eros elementum rhoncus. Sed ex urna, sagittis a cursus nec, tristique eu arcu.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, everything gets loaded properly, but the slideDown() animation runs, before the content is fully loaded and causes a jump.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it really matters, but I always find it safest to execute the `e.preventDefault()` as fast as possible, so at the start of each function, not the end

Comment: @myfunkyside Thank you, I have switched that around and will keep that in mind for the future!

Comment: Can you give examples of the exact values of `pageLoad ` for the *images*, the *iFrame*, and the *images+iFrame* scenario?

Comment: @myfunkyside Sure! I just added an example of the value of `pageLoad` to the original question.

Comment: That whole `<div class="project-ajax">...</div>` is stored into the `pageLoad` var?

Comment: @myfunkyside Sorry, I misunderstood your original question. The `pageLoad` var is being made here `var pageLoad = $j(this).prop("href");` and the value would be a link to a page that contains the content I added above (`<div class="project-ajax">...</div>`).

Comment: Yeah, okay, right. And then in `.load(pageLoad, function(){` the content of that URL (so `<div class="project-ajax">...</div>`) is being loaded into the `.project-container`. (Sorry, I know all this already works fine, I just need to get the full picture in order to determine if the solution I had in mind, will work)

Comment: @myfunkyside that is correct

Comment: Wait, can't you just put this: `$j('.project-ajax').on('load',function(){$j('.project-container').slideDown();});` on the line of your `.slideDown();`?

Comment: @myfunkyside just tried that and the function never fires

Comment: And if you change `$j('.project-ajax').on` to `$j('.project-container').on`? And if that doesn't work `$j(window).on`?

Comment: @myfunkyside Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64819/discussion-between-rgilkes-and-myfunkyside).

Comment: Sorry for another comment, just wanted to make sure you got my messages in the chat, 'cause I'm not sure if you get notifications from those messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the callback function like this

```
//On project click, run function
$j(".project-ajax-click").click(function(e){

    var pageLoad = $j(this).prop("href");

    //Bring project div to the top of page
    $j('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop': $j('#project').offset().top-$j('.navbar').height()}, 900, 'swing');

    $j('.project-container')
        .slideUp()
        .load(pageLoad, function(){
            $j(".project-flex").flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                slideshow: false,
                directionNav: false,
                controlNav: false,
            });

            $j('.flex-prev, .flex-next').on('click', function(){
                var href = $j(this).attr('href');
                $j('.project-flex').flexslider(href)
                return false;
            });

            $j(".project-close").click(function(e){
                $j('.project-container').slideUp(function(){
                    $j('.project-info').remove(); 
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        },function(){
            $('.project-container').slideDown();
        });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I'm already using the callback function (your example has two callback functions). If I move `$j('project-container').slideDown();` into the callback function, that doesn't work either. Please correct me if I am not understanding your explanation correctly.